# How to make JButton text appear?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

[image: compiled result]

In the above image the left shows code for the set of 4 seats in yellow on the left. I tried to change the font size to try to make it fit in the box but I can't get them to show up. For now the text on the JButtons are all "..." but I want them to display their labels, which are only 3 characters. What can I do to the JButtons to get them to display the labels? Perhaps removing the JButton border space?

Comment: Make use of appropriate layout managers, see [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details.  Use `JFrame#pack` instead of `JFrame#setSize`

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33227532/spacing-between-columns-of-jbuttons/33227603#33227603) for example

Comment: Would it be possible to eliminate the thick border around the text (left and right)? Maybe that could free up some space to see the text.

Comment: Maybe if you actually let the layout managers do there jobs correctly, you wouldn't be having issues

Answer (score 3):

> Would it be possible to eliminate the thick border around the text (left and right)?

The margin controls the space between the text and the Border:

```
seats[I].setMargin( new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5) );
```

Also, in the future post actual code, not a picture of the code. And the code should be in the form of a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) so we know exactly what your are doing.